# How to know the template of the main page in prestashop

Tags: prestashop

I want to know where is the main template of a prestashop project.

I come from Laravel and this is something weird to me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Prestashop **1.7** its in **themes/classic/templates/**

```
page.tpl for the home page
catalog/product.tpl for the product page
catalog/listing/product-list.tpl for any product list page
checkout/cart.tpl for the detailed cart
checkout/checkout.tpl for the checkout process
```

in Prestashop **1.6** , there is **no main.tpl** like in twig.
you just have something like this

```
header.tpl 
page_name.tpl 
footer.tpl
```

in **themes/default-bootstrap/**